# Nginx handling relative paths causes 404 errors

Tags: nginx

I have a problem that when I reverse proxy a page the files will relative paths are not found.

Example working:

```
https://lfportal.mohavecounty.us/bos/search.aspx?dbid=0&searchcommand=%28%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BMeeting%20Date%5D%3D%2211/23/2020%22%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BMeeting%20Type%5D%3D%22Special%22%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BItem%20Number%5D%3D%22Item%20001%22%7D%29%20
```

Which redirects to the search result:

```
https://lfportal.mohavecounty.us/bos/0/doc/1652027/Page1.aspx
```

On the file Page1.aspx there are paths using the relative path as shown in the example below

```
<img id="A_T0_0_1" unselectable="on" src="../../../Helper/TileData.aspx?reposName=MohaveDocs&amp;docID=1652027&amp;x=0&amp;y=1&amp;pageNum=1&amp;scale=3782&amp;ro=0&amp;time=1607098159588&amp;showAnn=1&amp;pageID=7493796&amp;search=">
```

Now with my redirect

```
https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/bos/search.aspx?dbid=0&searchcommand=%28%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BMeeting%20Date%5D%3D%2211/23/2020%22%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BMeeting%20Type%5D%3D%22Special%22%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BItem%20Number%5D%3D%22Item%20001%22%7D%29%20
```

The page loads but doesn't continue because it fails.  It give allot of 404 and looking at the address of one the image above in Chrome developer and the 404 error shows the address:

```
https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/Helper/TileData.aspx?reposName=MohaveDocs&docID=1652027&x=0&y=1&pageNum=1&scale=3782&ro=0&time=1607098058369&showAnn=1&pageID=7493796&search=
```

So it seems the root folder bos is missing.
https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/Helper/TileData.aspx?

Should be URL:
https://lfportal.mohavecounty.us/bos/Helper/TileData.aspx?

So it seems my proxy pass is not handling the relative attribute correctly.
Below is my sample Nginx site conf.  The problem is occurring in the second if the condition

```
if ($saved_redirect_location !~* "10.4.1.81") { .. }
```

My conf file:

```
server{

    listen       443 ssl http2; # default_server;
    server_name  lfdocs.mohave.gov;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/lfdocs_mohave_gov_access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/lfdocs_mohave_gov_error.log info;
    
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/mohave_gov_ssl.conf;

    location / {

        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;       

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;

        proxy_pass http://10.4.1.81/;


        # This is used to handle the multiple redirect 301 that the server is doing
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;     

    }   

    location @handle_redirects {
        set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';

    
        if ($saved_redirect_location ~* "10.4.1.81") {
            add_header X-debug-message 1$saved_redirect_location always;
            proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
        }

        if ($saved_redirect_location !~* "10.4.1.81") {
            add_header X-debug-message http://10.4.1.81$saved_redirect_location always;
            proxy_pass http://10.4.1.81$saved_redirect_location;
        }       
    }   
}
```

In Chrome developer I look at the custom header x-debug-message and has the value:

```
x-debug-message: http://10.4.1.81/bos/0/doc/1652027/Page1.aspx
```

I have tried removing the trailing slash under the location section from an article I read but it didn't work.

Any ideas on why the relative paths are not loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative paths are added by your backend application. nginx does not touch the paths in any way.

If your backend application uses relative paths, then your frontend URL must be at same depth as backend URL.

In your first example:

```
https://lfportal.mohavecounty.us/bos/0/doc/1652027/Page1.aspx
```

The URL is on fourth subdir level. This means browser can resolve `../../../` to `/bos`.

In your second example:

```
https://lfdocs.mohave.gov/bos/search.aspx?dbid=0&searchcommand=%28%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BMeeting%20Date%5D%3D%2211/23/2020%22%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BMeeting%20Type%5D%3D%22Special%22%7D%20%26%20%7B%5BBOS%20Agenda%20Packets%5D%3A%5BItem%20Number%5D%3D%22Item%20001%22%7D%29%20
```

The URL is on second subdir level. Now, browser tries to resolve `../../../` URL, and it ends up being `/` URL.

My recommendation is that you replace the relative URLs with site-root relative URLs: `/bos/Helper/TileData.aspx?reposName=MohaveDocs&amp;docID=1652027&amp;x=0&amp;y=1&amp;pageNum=1&amp;scale=3782&amp;ro=0&amp;time=1607098159588&amp;showAnn=1&amp;pageID=7493796&amp;search`

Another issue with your URLs is that the ampersand characters are URL encoded, which might lead to undesired end result.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately is a vendor product which I cant change.